# using html for an image

Tags: html

I have an image for adding files(is also add button) and I want it to be disabled(or say make it grey) when they are no files.and when they are files to be added it should enable the user to add files.

Comment: I think you are talking about an imagebutton.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use two separate images for active and inactive buttons.

Comment: They are list of files from which user can add them,if they are no files we want to disable the add_image(disable as in make it grey in colour or make it inactive) but when they are list of files the add_image should be active.We don't want to throw an exeption or pop-up

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you need, but Ill give it a go :)

An image for adding files:

```
<input name="AddFile" type="image" src="image.gif" disabled="True">
```

Use a Javascript function to active the image-button:

```
function enableField()
{
document.form1.AddFile.disabled=false;
}
```

Comment: They are list of files from which user can add them,if they are no files we want to disable the add_image(disable as in make it grey in colour or make it inactive) but when they are list of files the add_image should be active.We don't want to throw an exeption or pop-up